# Do you make a Use Case Narrative of a general use case?

Tags: uml, use-case, diagrams

I have this use case diagram. As you can see, "Rate Service Provider" is the general use case of "Rate on Computer" and "Rate Online" use cases. Since those two use cases are specific, I know they have separate use case narratives. Now my question is that do you need to create a use case narrative for a general use case? The general use case has almost the same behavior as the two specific use cases. Thank you. :)

[image: My use case diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, base on my previous experienced. The rate computer and rate online will be the alternative sequence in your use case narrative.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a narrative that describes the behavior common to both sub-cases for Rate Service Provider.  In that narrative, mention the inherited cases, and provide a separate narrative for each of them.  Much as you would do with a narrative for a use case that has included use cases.